# IntegrityError: foreign key violation upon delete

Tags: sql, database, django, postgresql, django-models

I have Order and Shipment model. Shipment has a foreign key to Order.

```
class Order(...):
   ...

class Shipment()
   order = m.ForeignKey('Order')
   ...
```

Now in one of my views I want do delete order object along with all related objects. So I invoke order.delete().

I have Django 1.0.4, PostgreSQL 8.4 and I use transaction middleware, so whole request is enclosed in single transaction.

The problem is that upon order.delete() I get:

```
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 28, in _commit
return self.connection.commit()

IntegrityError: update or delete on table "main_order" violates 
foreign key constraint "main_shipment_order_id_fkey" on table "main_shipment"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(45) is still referenced from table "main_shipment".
```

I checked in connection.queries that proper queries are executed in proper order. First shipment is deleted, after that django executes delete on order row:

```
{'time': '0.000', 'sql': 'DELETE FROM "main_shipment" WHERE "id" IN (17)'},
{'time': '0.000', 'sql': 'DELETE FROM "main_order" WHERE "id" IN (45)'}
```

Foreign key have ON DELETE NO ACTION (default) and is initially deferred. I don't know why I get foreign key constraint violation.

I also tried to register pre_delete signal and manually delete shipment objects before delete on order is called, but it resulted in the same error.

I can change ON DELETE behaviour for this key in Postgres but it would be just a hack, I wonder if anyone has a better idea what's going on here.

There is also a small detail, my Order model inherits from Cart model, so it actually doesn't have id field but cart_ptr_id and after DELETE on order is executed there is also DELETE on cart, but it seems unrelated? to the shipment->order problem so I simplified it in the example.

Comment: Well I tried this in psql console, and the same result, so it is strictly postgreql matter. Maybye I don't get how deferred works.

Comment: Could you provide relevant create table SQL?

Comment: WHy are you deleting orders that have shipments? Generally this is something you would want to fail. You don't want to delete actual shipments, ever.

Comment: Well, because this order is not yet submitted. This is part of order placing use case, when someone removes all items from the order I just  remove the order and redirect back to the empty cart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> DETAIL:  Key (id)=(45) is still
>   referenced from table "main_shipment".

There is still a record referencing to id 45. You did delete record 17 in main_shipment before, but there might be others as well. You have to delete all records in main_shipment referencing to id 45 in main_order. If not, the database protects you from doing harm to your data.

Comment: Ahhhhhh :/ I was fighting with it so long and I just realized that later in python code, in higher code block, I have shipment.save() :/ And I didn't notice it in conn.queries output because it was printed before shipment.save() is called.