# Why an exception can't be caught in Django view and how to debug

Tags: python, django, exception, error-handling

I'm quite happy with this delete view:

```
def price_unit_delete(request, pk):
    pu = PriceUnit.objects.get(pk=pk)
    template = 'includes/modal/modal_form.html'
    if request.POST:
        pu.delete()
        template = 'dashboard_staff/settings/includes/priceunits.html'
    ctx = {'action': reverse("dashboard_staff:settings_delete_priceunit", args=(pu.pk, )),
           'title': 'do you really want to delete me ?',
           'form': PriceUnitDeleteForm(),
           'priceunits': PriceUnit.objects.all()}
    return TemplateResponse(request, template, ctx)
```

When an item is referenced somewhere else as a foreign key, it fails. I thought to catch this integrity error (firstly raised by psycopg2 and secondly by django.db itself) using a `try` block.

Indeed you can do in python console:

````
# in case of ```o``` being referenced somewhere else, returns False

def delete(o):
    try:
        o.delete()
    except:
        return False
````

I naively thought to include such a block in the view like this:

```
   if request.POST:
        try:
            pu.delete()
        except:
            return JsonResponse({'data': _(
                "You can't delete this object as it is used somewhere else."
            )}, status=400)
```

But in this case the exception is not caught. I wrote this view as a CBV as well, it fails to catch the exception too.

I tried this code in an other project and it works.

**Why this doesn't work in case of Integrity exception? and how could I debug it?**

Here is the traceback of the exception I want to catch:

```
  File "/home/emilio/.virtualenvs/rdt_2.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 240, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
psycopg2.IntegrityError: update or delete on table "prices_priceunit" violates foreign key constraint "prices_prestationtyp_default_price_unit_i_c6ec94f9_fk_prices_pr" on table "prices_prestationtype"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "prices_prestationtype".


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/emilio/.virtualenvs/rdt_2.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/emilio/.virtualenvs/rdt_2.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/emilio/.virtualenvs/rdt_2.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/emilio/.virtualenvs/rdt_2.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 240, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/home/emilio/.virtualenvs/rdt_2.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 262, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/home/emilio/.virtualenvs/rdt_2.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 240, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/home/emilio/.virtualenvs/rdt_2.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/emilio/.virtualenvs/rdt_2.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 240, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: update or delete on table "prices_priceunit" violates foreign key constraint "prices_prestationtyp_default_price_unit_i_c6ec94f9_fk_prices_pr" on table "prices_prestationtype"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "prices_prestationtype".
```

Comment: Looking at the traceback might help us help you. Please add it. here.

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543461/integrityerror-foreign-key-violation-upon-delete

Comment: @NalinDobhal this is not helping. I know what the error means. The problem here is that it is impossible to handle it in a ```try``` block as usual. The most suprising is that the try block works fine in a console python.